# Add service accounts to public Google groups

Tags: google-drive-api, service-accounts, google-groups, google-groups-api

How can I add service accounts to public Google groups?
I wanted to add service accounts to public Google groups because they were linked to some directory in Google drive and let service accounts work with them. Is there any way to do so?

I don't know how to address service accounts to itself join public Google groups. And let them access the Google drive files.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask]

Comment: Same issue. When I try to add the email address of the service account to the list of shared functions, google tells me `you can't add account which are not from google yet`. For a google service account. Google permission system is a nightmare to use.